# How do I change the color of the tooltip for only one component?

Tags: java, swing, tooltip

How do I change the color of the tooltip for only one component?

I know you can do the following for changing tooltip colors:

```
UIManager.put("ToolTip.background", new ColorUIResource(255, 247, 200));
```

But this changes the tooltip background for all component, not just one.

Any easy solutions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to provide a custom [`JTooltip`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JToolTip.html) for the component.

Take a look at [JComponent#createToolTip](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#createToolTip%28%29)

From the Java Docs

> Returns the instance of JToolTip that should be used to display the
>   tooltip. Components typically would not override this method, but it
>   can be used to cause different tooltips to be displayed differently.

Answer (score 9):

+1 to @MadProgrammer and @Reimeus for their advice and example.

These are both correct.

To add...

There is no default way to do this. You have to extend the `ToolTip` class, to create your own custom `ToolTip` with foreground and background color, and then extend `JComponent`s class (`JButton`, `JLabel`, etc. are all `JComponent`s ) and override its`createToolTip()` method and sets your custom `ToolTip` as the the `JComponent`s `ToolTip`, like this :

Here is an example I made:

[image]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JToolTip;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

/**
 *
 * @author David
 */
public class CustomJToolTipTest {

    private JFrame frame;

    public CustomJToolTipTest() {
        initComponents();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new CustomJToolTipTest();
            }
        });
    }

    private void initComponents() {
        frame = new JFrame("Test");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setResizable(false);


        JButton button = new JButton("button") {
            //override the JButtons createToolTip method
            @Override
            public JToolTip createToolTip() {
                return (new CustomJToolTip(this));
            }
        };
        button.setToolTipText("I am a button with custom tooltip");

        frame.add(button);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}

class CustomJToolTip extends JToolTip {

    public CustomJToolTip(JComponent component) {
        super();
        setComponent(component);
        setBackground(Color.black);
        setForeground(Color.red);
    }
}
```

Comment: @dingfelder sorry there was a flaw in the code. Please see update

Answer (score 5):

There is no standard way to do this, but you could override `JComponent.createToolTip()`. Here is a button example:

```
MyButton testButton = new MyButton("Move Mouse Over Button");
testButton.setToolTipText("Some text");

class MyButton extends JButton {

   public MyButton(String text) {
      super(text);
   }

   @Override
   public JToolTip createToolTip() {
      return (new MyCustomToolTip(this));
   }
}

class MyCustomToolTip extends JToolTip {
   public MyCustomToolTip(JComponent component) {
      super();
      setComponent(component);
      setBackground(Color.black);
      setForeground(Color.red);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I won't recommend this if you have access to the source code. But if you haven't, you can change the color by utilizing the HTML formatting capability.

```
JButton b = new JButton();
b.setToolTipText("<html><div style='margin:0 -3 0 -3; padding: 0 3 0 3; background:green;'>My Text</div></html>");
```

You need the negative margin, because there exist a standard margin which will not be colored otherwise. We make up for the margin by adding a padding. 3 px seems to work for the metal LAF.